# Using module variables for workbooks selected by user

Tags: vba, excel

Haven't really had the chance to use module variables before and unfortunately even after reading about them I can't seem to make it work.

My issues is that I'm trying to use a variable assigned as a workbook which the user browses for and use it in different subs.

As an example code of what I mean:

```
Sub GetFile()

Dim fNameAndPath As Variant

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

    Call one
    Call two

End Sub

Sub one()

    With fNameAndPath

        'do stuff

    End With

End Sub

Sub two()

    With fNameAndPath

        'do stuff

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `One` and `Two` cannot "see" `fNameAndPath` as it is defined within `GetFile`.  Variables defined within a sub/function are said to be local to that sub/function.  You can either pass the variable as a parameter or move the declaration outside of `GetFile`.  Generally speaking, you want to restrict the number of vars declared at the module level (or above).  They can be hard to keep track of.

Answer (score 2):

Its best practice to restrict the scope of a variable (where its visible) to the smallest area as possible - in this case send the variable as an argument, that way the variable lives only within the subs that declare or use it.

```
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

one fNameAndPath 
two fNameAndPath 

End Sub
```

And receive them as:

```
Sub one(fNameAndPath as Variant)
///

Sub two(fNameAndPath as Variant)
///
```

(`With fNameAndPath` is not valid as `fNameAndPath` is a string not an object)

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. One thing I don't understand though, how does "one fNameAndPath" work in the main sub, what does it do?

Comment: it calls `one` passing `fNameAndPath` as an argument. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx